# RXJS как сделать зависимые запросы?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Как сделать зависимые запросы?

```
const streamClickRefresh = fromEvent(refresh, 'click')
    .pipe(
        switchMap( v => ajax.getJSON(gitUrl))
        
    );
```

У меня имеется запрос помещенный в switchMap, как на основе него сделать еще один запрос?

Answer (score 1):

По сути нужно просто добавить еще один `switchMap`. Результат выполнения от первого `switchMap` будет передан дальше в `pipe`, и на его основе можно сделать второй запрос.

```
const streamClickRefresh = fromEvent(refresh, 'click')
.pipe(
    // результатом firstRequest будет firstRequestResult, который передается в pipe
    switchMap( data => firstRequest(data)),
    // на основе firstRequestResult делается второй запрос
    switchMap( firstRequestResult => secondRequest(firstRequestResult)),
);
```